# is there an built-in clojure function to produce 'applied' function

Tags: clojure

I found

```
(defn applied [fn] #(apply fn %))
```

is a very common function transform utility. Is there an built-in implementation in clojure stdlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you describe:

```
(partial apply fn)
```

Comment: Yes. Not perfect (I expect a single function symbol) but this works.